# How to serialize into a string and then de-serialize it back (for Redis)?

Tags: redis, julia

```
x = IOBuffer()
serialize(x, "ll")
readall(x) # ""
```

Why does `readall(x)` return an empty string?

#### Update

It seems I have to

either:

```
x = IOBuffer()
serialize(x, "ll")
seekstart(x)
readall(x)
```

or

```
x = IOBuffer()
serialize(x, "ll")
takebuf_string(x)
```

But both of them gives me `UnicodeError: invalid character index`

Ultimately I want to get a string representation of serialized object, store it into Redis.

And later fetch the string from Redis, and then deserialize from it.

#### Solution

```
x = IOBuffer()
serialize(x, "ll")
takebuf_array(x)
```

It is not a string, it is a bytearray. Julia string is stricter than Python 2 `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to deserialize is `deserialize(stream)`

```
x = IOBuffer()
serialize(x, "ll")
seekstart(x)
deserialize(x)
```

Serialize writes a value to a stream so that it can be reconstructed into it's original value (or as close to as possible) at a later point by using `deserialize`. Typing `?serialize` in the Julia repl will give some details:

```
help?> serialize
search: serialize Serializer deserialize SerializationState

  serialize(stream, value)

  Write an arbitrary value to a stream in an opaque format, such that it can be read back by deserialize. The read-back value will be as identical as possible to the original. In general, this process will not work if the reading and writing are done by different versions of Julia, or an instance of Julia with a different system image. Ptr values are serialized as all-zero bit patterns (NULL).
```

This is different from writing arbitrary bytes to a stream, check out `?write` and try using that with something like `readall` or `takebuf_string`

Comment: Is there any way to get a string form in between?

Comment: If you specifically want to pass a string, I believe you will need to write your own to string, and from string functions. Then you could use `write` and `readall` to write the string and read the string from the stream. The format Julia uses for serialize is meant to be opaque, and therefore not human readable like a string. -- As a side note, it sounds like you're doing something funky, and you might want to reconsider the approach, but I won't judge without knowing the requirements of what you're trying to accomplish!

Comment: Sorry let me explain my situation a bit more. I want to save the string into Redis.

Comment: I think you're stuck writing your own to/from methods, or piggy backing on something like JSON encoding. Note that serialize / de-serialize would  definitely *not* be safe, as with each version of Julia (or the package your type comes from), the format may change.